# Using CoreML with React Native

Tags: swift, react-native, coreml

[image]

I am getting the error

> Argument labels '(image:)' do not match any available overloads

I followed this tutorial [here](https://www.appcoda.com/coreml-introduction/) and apple's documentation, but when I tried to bridge the framework to except an image from React Native I started getting this error. The bridge between Swift and Reac Native is working, only when I start trying to use coreML did I get errors

I think it has something to do with the new swift syntax but I am not sure how to fix it, I also haven't seen anyone using CoreML with React Native yet

Here is my full function:

```
import Foundation
import CoreML

@objc(Printer)
class Printer: NSObject {

  @objc func imageRec(_ image:CGImage) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
let model = Inceptionv3();

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 299, height: 299), true, 1.0)
//image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 299, height: 299))
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(newImage.size.width), Int(newImage.size.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, attrs, &pixelBuffer)
guard (status == kCVReturnSuccess) else {
  return nil
}

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)

let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let context = CGContext(data: pixelData, width: Int(newImage.size.width), height: Int(newImage.size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)

context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: newImage.size.height)
context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

UIGraphicsPushContext(context!)
newImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newImage.size.width, height: newImage.size.height))
UIGraphicsPopContext()
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

guard let prediction = try? model.prediction(image: newImage) else {
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to init modelInput (this is an autogenerate class when you add and data model) class, then send modelInput to prediction.

Following is code snippet that may help:

```
        // create indupt data model
        // in your case this must be taking image as argument
        let input = ProfitPredictorInput.init(R_D_Spend: 
          Double(rndInv)!, Administration: Double(adminInv)!, 
           Marketing_Spend: Double(marketingInv)!)

        // give input data model to your mlmodel
        let outData = try mlModel?.prediction(input: input)
```

you can use [this](https://github.com/prafullakumar/ML-Example) for reference.

Comment: I'm confused at what R_D_Spend, Administration, and Marketing_Spend are? I tried doing this but I get the same error just on the init line.

Comment: R_D_Spend, Administration, Marketing_Spend are the parameter for my ML Model.  Open Your MLModel in Xcode. it will show input-output parameter for your ml-model you have to use that instead.

Comment: Hmmm the parameter is 'image'